# Is making my server send a mail from the email of a registered user impossible?

Tags: php, laravel, email

Right now I have functioning emailing on my Laravel back-end, however, the email is always sent from my gmail email. I was wondering if it is even possible to make the message appear as if it was send from the email of the registered user who's sending the message. For example right now it works like this:

Registered user George with email George@gmail.com sends a mail to user Ivan with email Ivan@gmail.com. When Ivan receives the email, the FROM field shows my mail username.

I'm wondering if it's even possible to set up the email code, so that it appears that the email comes from the user who's actually sending the email?

I reckon that is impossible because you'd need to somehow authenticate that you are in fact the owner of that email, before being able to send a message. Otherwise you can make emails that appear to be send from one email, when they're in fact from another.

I assume this is a very foolish question, but I just started fiddling with emails today and it's quite confusing.

That's how I send emails:

EmailController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendMail(Request $request){

        $title = "Email Title";
        $body = "Email Body";
        $receiver = "test123@abv.bg";

        $details = [
            'title' => $title,
            'body' => $body
        ];

        \Mail::to($receiver)->send(new \App\Mail\HiMail($details));

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Mail.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class HiMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $details;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject("Test Mail")->view("emails.hi");
    }
}
```

mail.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ $details['title'] }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $details['body'] }}</p>
        <p>Thank you</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well email is as we all know easy to spoof but I assume you are not asking how to do that as you would risk your own email account falling into disrepute

Comment: `Is making my server send a mail from the email of a registered user impossible?`...it's not impossible (the basic SMTP protocol is pretty lax about it) but it's a very bad idea, as it will probably make your message look like spam / spoofing to a mailserver - if the domain of the mail and the domain of the mailserver don't match then that's generally a negative flag on the message for any spam analysis tool. A better idea might be to put the "sender" email in the Reply-To field of the message, so at least any replies would be redirected to it (assuming that's what you want)

Comment: With Google as SMTP it _is_ impossible, because they simply won’t let you do that.

Comment: You might like to look up how to set the ReplyTo in your package, then set that to be the users address

Comment: Thanks fellas, I'd have to read up about the things you mentioned because I'm quite clueless right now. I'll give ReplyTo a look first.

Comment: The best way to send emails from different accounts is... (unexpectedly) sending it from different accounts. Your app can just use several different credentials for sending mail from required address by connecting to selected account. In Gmail itself you can also add (at least some time ago that was possible) alternative email addresses that are allowed to be showed as a sender, however some servers/clients thread it as a SPAM.

Comment: @biesior Perhaps, but in this scenario I think it's very unlikely that the PHP application records the mail credentials and connectivity details of all its registered users. I don't think the list of possible senders is a fixed, pre-defined list - it's "any user who registered on the website", which is why attempting to do it by spoofing the "from" field is a bad idea, and why it won't be feasible to actually connect to all those users' mail accounts directly..

Comment: It's not about *recording* rather about *configuration*. But of course in general you're right ADyson, trying to manipulate sender's data *can be* get as a spam-machina.

Comment: @biesior not sure what you mean by "recording" vs "configuration" here? Can you clarify? My point was that `Your app can just use several different credentials for sending mail from required address by connecting to selected account` isn't realistic in the context where the email address you want to send from is a random one provided by a user who signed up to the site. It could be from any provider, and the user isn't going to input their SMTP server config and their email password into the website. So, while your suggestion might be relevant in some other situation, it isn't for this one.